# ADMOB - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, admob

I did everything like the tutorial tells the AdMob site, put the layout in XML, imported the path Google Play Sevices and added the lines of code from the tutorial, my application compiles, but no longer opens on your smartphone.

Follows the code.

Classe

```
package your.CalculoHE.namespace;


import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class CalculoHoraExtraActivity extends DroidGap {    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.sobreaviso);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);

        // Consultar o AdView como um recurso e carregar uma solicitaÃ§Ã£o.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }    
   }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-*******"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hora extras"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.CalculoHE.namespace"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".CalculoHoraExtraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>


    </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what Do You mean exactly? The app is crashing, not opening, or is just no Ad to see?

Comment: If there are any crashes, please post your stack trace. Importantly, never show your real adunit id when posting. Remove it or replace with "***"  Someone might use it for bad purposes which can lead to admob banning you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

To:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: MJ93, The constructor AdRequest() is undefined

Comment: Opiatefuchs, does not open!

Comment: Make sure `import com.google.ads.AdRequest;` is imported. The constructor does not need any parameters.

Comment: The same message persists even after you have imported

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You can't use both "com.google.android.gms.ads.*" and "com.google.ads.*". You must stick to one package. Either the old admob sdk or new admob via the google play services. @Paulo, what do you mean by the app doesn't open. Care to share your stack trace(error log)?

Comment: The problem I'm having now is with the builder "The constructor AdRequest() is undefined"

Comment: import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

Comment: @Nana The problem I'm having now is with the builder "The constructor AdRequest() is undefined"

Comment: Don't use new AdRequest(). Use new AdRequest.Builder().build(); instead, since you're using the google play services library. Does the app crash? If it does, post the log(stack trace)